# Linear dependence with functions

Tags: linear-algebra

let S($\mathbb{R}$,$\mathbb{R}$) be the Set of all functions f: $\mathbb{R}$ -> $\mathbb{R}$. Consider for t $\in \mathbb{R}$ the element $(f_t) \in S(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ with:

$f_t(x)$ = $\begin{cases} 0  &\text{for}& x < t \\ 1&\text{for}& x \geq t \end{cases}$

Decide whether the family $(f_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ is linear (in)dependent.

I know how to check whether a family of vectors is linear dependent, and that functions can be vector spaces, too but I need a hint right now how to solve this task.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the definition of linear independence. A set of vectors $V$ is *linearly independent* if for any **finite** linear combination of vectors in $V$ that equals $0$, the coefficients of that combination are all $0$. Otherwise, we say $V$ is *linearly dependent*.

To show whether or not your set $V=\{f_t \in S(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})\,|\,t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is linearly independent, you must show whether or not it holds that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and all real $t_1<t_2<\ldots<t_n$ the *only* solution $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n \in \mathbb{R}$ to

$$c_1\cdot f_{t_1}+c_2\cdot f_{t_2}+ \ldots +c_n \cdot f_{t_n} = 0$$

is given by $c_1=c_2=\ldots=c_n=0$. Here, $c_1\cdot f_{t_1}+c_2\cdot f_{t_2}+ \ldots +c_n \cdot f_{t_n} = 0$ is an equality of functions, meaning that

$$c_1\cdot f_{t_1}(x)+c_2\cdot f_{t_2}(x)+\ldots+c_n\cdot f_{t_n}(x) = 0$$

is true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Do you think you can take it from here? Try writing an expression for $$f(x)=c_1\cdot f_{t_1}(x)+c_2\cdot f_{t_2}(x)+\ldots+c_n\cdot f_{t_n}(x)$$

EDIT: Consider the equation

\begin{align}\tag{1}\label{eq}c_1\cdot f_{t_1}(x)+c_2\cdot f_{t_2}(x)+\ldots+c_n\cdot f_{t_n}(x) = 0\end{align}

Here, the equation holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the $t_i$ are distinct and the 'unknowns' are $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n$. One solution is $c_1=c_2=\ldots=0$; this is always true. If this is the **only** solution (called the *trivial* solution), then the $f_{t_i}$ form a linearly independent set. If there is another solution, then they form a linearly dependent set.

For instance, $(1,0),(0,1)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ are linearly independent, because $x\cdot(1,0)+y\cdot(0,1)=(x,y)$ and hence $x\cdot(1,0)+y\cdot(0,1)=(0,0)$ if and only if $x=y=0$. In other words, the trivial solution is the only solution.

On the other hand, $(1,0),(2,0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ are linearly dependent. Indeed, $x\cdot(1,0)+y\cdot(2,0)=(x+2y,0)$, so $x=2,y=-1$ is a nontrivial solution to $x\cdot(1,0)+y\cdot(2,0)=(0,0)$.

EDIT EDIT: Okay, big hint.

Assume without loss of generality that $t_1<t_2<\ldots<t_n$. How does the LHS of equation $\eqref{eq}$ look like when $x<t_1$? What about when $t_1\leq x<t_2$?

Comment: to be honest, no. What do you mean with expression?

Comment: I mean the rule for $f(x)$. Like the one you wrote for $f_t$:

$$f_t(x) = \begin{cases} 0  &\text{for}& x < t \\ 1&\text{for}& x \geq t \end{cases}$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to the Topic. So I have to write a "rule" for $f(x)$ when $f(x)$ linear dependent and when $f(x)$ linear independent?

Comment: I've made edits to correct a small notation mistake and try and explain more clearly.

Comment: thanks, but I know all of this. My Problem is using these informations on my problem. I just don't know how I can find a solution without the default Methods(like solving an equation system) used on vectors like the ones you mentioned.

Comment: What difficulty have you faced with applying the concepts to this problem?

Comment: I've made edits on my last comment.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer and given you a big hint.

Comment: When $x < t_1$ then, according to the expression $f_t(x) = 0$ right? So we are multiplying $c_1, c_2...c_n$ with 0. And when $t_1 \leq x < t_2$ we got for $f_t(x) = 0$ again.

Comment: When $t_1\leq x<t_2$, not all terms of the sum $$c_1\cdot f_{t_1}(x)+c_2\cdot f_{t_2}(x)+\ldots+c_n\cdot f_{t_n}(x)$$ are $0$.

Comment: right, so its alternating 1 and 0? For $t_1 \leq x < t_2$ we are multiplying $c_1$ with 1 because $x \geq t_1$ but x is less then $t_2$ so we are adding $c_2 * 0$. But linear dependence depends on c not on x right? Can we find an x so that we aren't mapping on 0?

Comment: When $t_1\leq x<t_2$, we have that $f_{t_1}(x)=1$ and that $f_{t_2}(x)=\ldots=f_{t_n}(x)=0$. Hence, the LHS becomes $c_1\cdot 1 + c_2\cdot 0 +\ldots c_n\cdot 0=0$. What does that tell you about $c_1$? Can you adapt this reasoning to make similar conclusions about $c_2,\ldots,c_n$?

Comment: when the lhs with $c_1*1 + c_2 *0 + ...c_n*0 = 0$ then $c_1$ has to be 0. Because otherwise the equality of functions would equal c_1 not 0.

Comment: That is correct, $c_1=0$. The argument with $t_1\leq x<t_2$ doesn't tell you anything about $c_2,\ldots,c_n$. But now that you know $c_1=0$, look into $t_2\leq x<t_3$ and conclude something about $c_2$. Can you use induction to finish the proof?

Comment: Complete induction over the indices? It holds for $c_1$ then we can show that it holds for $c_{n+1}$? $\sum^n_{i=1}c_n*f_t(x)$ = 0 => $c_n = 0$?

Comment: The induction is that if it holds for $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_k$ then it holds for $c_{k+1}$. Try to write it down carefully. Start with the case $t_2\leq x < t_3$.

Comment: Oh, so that we have $a_1 * f_1(x)+a_2*f_2(x)+...+a_k*f_t(x)+a_{k+1}*f_t(x) = 0$ Now, we know that $c_1,c_2,...,c_n = 0$ and that $t_{k} \leq x < t_{k+1}$?

Comment: More like: let $t_k \leq x < t_{k+1}$. From equation $(1)$ and the definition of $f_t$, it follows that $c_1+c_2+\ldots+c_k+c_{k+1}=0$. Now we use the induction hypothesis; since $c_1=c_2=\ldots=c_k=0$, it follows that $c_{k+1}$ is also $0$.